# What is wrong with this jquery array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Probably something really simple but I cant fathom it out. I have the following command. That returns a json array.

```
var zz = fm.request({
                    data : {cmd : 'url', target : hash},
            preventFail : true,
            options: {async: true},


        })


        alert (zz.cmd); // or alert (zz.url);//  tried every combination I can think of. Must be something wrong with the way I am calling it.
```

This outputs the following json.

```
{"url":"https:\/\/test.com\/s\/tx74i3t9cet49xi\/vlc-record-2009-10-03-06h26m55s-http___79.125.42.98_film4_ls_auth%3D2e2fd32b2d221ce406085c03ec01722f-.ts","debug":{"connector":"php","phpver":"5.3.15","time":1.9966609477997,"memory":"4852Kb \/ 3932Kb \/ 128M","upload":"","volumes":[{"id":"l1_","name":"localfilesystem","mimeDetect":"finfo","imgLib":"gd"},{"id":"d2_","name":"dropbox","mimeDetect":"finfo","imgLib":"gd"}],"mountErrors":[]}}
```

I just need to alert the url. I am getting undefined, or nothing at all.

Post request.

```
cmd         url
target    d2_LzY4NV9DbGllbnRCdWdzXzIueGxzeA
Source   cmd=url&target=d2_LzY4NV9DbGllbnRCdWdzXzIueGxzeA
```

Comment: You're request is async (`options: {async: true}`), but you're trying to use the result in an synchronous way ...

Comment: what is the fm.request is returning? can you post request function code in your question?

Comment: Hi Yograj, is this what you mean. cmd = url
target = d2_LzY4NV9DbGllbnRCdWdzXzIueGxzeA
Source =
cmd=url&target=d2_LzY4NV9DbGllbnRCdWdzXzIueGxzeA

Answer (score 0):

it should be `alert(zz.data.cmd)`

Comment: yeah but he paste the JSON output, and there is no data class which he can access.

Comment: Yes still did not work. Get TypeError: Cannot read property 'cmd' of undefined {}.

Comment: Read the question again, a little more closely this time. It looks like zz.cmd.url would work. If not, I will delete my answer

Answer (score 0):

An extra comma after option hash.
You can validate your JSON data / hash at www.jsonlint.org
PLUS what @Ray posted

```
{
"data": {
    "cmd": "url",
    "target": "hash"
},
"preventFail": true,
"options": {
    "async": true
}
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Tried that and still get undefined error. Confusing me :-(

Comment: Have you noticed the quotes?  I pasted it in the chrome console and it just worked fine.